# How to run parts of your Kedro pipeline conditionally?

Tags: python, pipeline, kedro

I have a big pipeline, taking a few hours to run. A small part of it needs to run quite often, how do I run it without triggering the entire pipeline?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are multiple ways to specify which nodes or parts of your pipeline to run.

1. Use `kedro run` parameters like `--to-nodes`/`--from-nodes`/`--node` to explicitly define what needs to be run.
2. In `kedro>=0.15.2` you can define multiple pipelines, and then run only one of them with `kedro run --pipeline <name>`. If no `--pipeline` parameter is specified, the default pipeline is run. The default pipeline might combine several other pipelines. More information about using modular pipelines: https://kedro.readthedocs.io/en/latest/04_user_guide/06_pipelines.html#modular-pipelines
3. Use tags. Tag a small portion of your pipeline with something like "small", and then do `kedro run --tag small`. Read more here: https://kedro.readthedocs.io/en/latest/04_user_guide/05_nodes.html#tagging-nodes

Comment: +1 We use tags most often for this type of work.  Thanks for sharing the modular-pipelines link.  This is a feature that we have yet to really explore.

Answer (score 1):

I would reccomend getting your tags or piplines setup to run correctly from the cli  as @idanov suggested.  It will be much easier for you in the long run moving to production.  I would also add that you can do quite a bit of ad hoc pipeline trimming and running inside of python, here are some examples.

**filter by tags**

```py
nodes = pipeline.only_nodes_with_tags('cars')
```

**filter by node**

```py
nodes = pipeline.only_nodes('b_int_cars')
```

**filter nodes like**

```py
query_string = 'cars'
nodes = [
   node.name 
   for node in pipeline.nodes 
   if query_string in node.name
   ]
pipeline.only_nodes(*nodes)
```

**only nodes with tags** *or*

```py
nodes = pipeline.only_nodes_with_tags('cars', 'trains')
```

**only nodes with tags** *and*

```py
raw_nodes = pipeline.only_nodes_with_tags('raw')
car_nodes = pipeline.only_nodes_with_tags('cars')
raw_car_nodes = raw_nodes & car_nodes
```

```py
raw_nodes = (
   pipeline
   .only_nodes_with_tags('raw')
   .only_nodes_with_tags('cars')
   )
```

**add pipelines**

```py
car_nodes = pipeline.only_nodes_with_tags('cars')
train_nodes = pipeline.only_nodes_with_tags('trains')
transportation_nodes = car_nodes + train_nodes
```

The above was a snippet from my personal [kedro notes](https://waylonwalker.com/notes/kedro/).